# angularjs - access url parameters in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, url-parameters

I am trying to access url params in my controller:

I found this example, but I get an error that I think is related to loading the relevant modules.

```
app.controller('WidgetCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    var param1 = $routeParams.param1;
    var param2 = $routeParams.param2;

    var vm = $scope;

    vm.data = "test";

}]);
```

Error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

In my html I have:

```
    <script src=".../angular-1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src=".../angular-1.2.21/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

What is the proper wat to access the url params and use them in the controller? which modules I need to load?

Comment: add `$http` in array of DI.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, you're not injecting $http, so it should be:

```
app.controller('WidgetCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', function ($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
```

That should get rid of that error.

Comment: thanks, apparently I forgot to depend on ngRoute.. now there is no error, but looks like the $routeParams object is empty. how can I actually access the params?

Comment: Your html script, has three dots rather than two, is that just a spelling mistake?

Comment: yes its a spelling mistake, I load the scripts from a local library. there is no error, just the $routeParams is empty